# Alamofire request doesn't return

Tags: ios, swift, request, alamofire

I want to create an app that with a textField and a label. The textField will read the input and using Alamofire to check if the input exist. (The url will return JSON Bool.) A helper function called getReturnVal is to get the return value from the url.

However, the nameExist variable is always nil and it seems like the helper function never goes into the two cases. Please advise how should I fix this problem.

Thank you in advance.

My code is as below.

import UIKit

import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
var nameValid: Bool = false

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == nameField {
        guard let username = textField.text, !username.isEmpty else {
            nameValid = false
            return
        }
        let url = "https://bismarck.sdsu.edu/hometown/nicknameexists?name=" + username
        print(url)
        let nameExist = getReturnVal(url: url, type: Bool.self)
        if nameExist! {
            nameLabel.text = "Exist"
            nameValid = false
        } else {
            nameLabel.text = "Valid"
            nameValid = true
        }

    }

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func getReturnVal<T>(url: String, type: T.Type) -> T? {
    var jsonObject: T?
    print("enter------------")
    Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                jsonObject = (JSON as! T)
                print("SUCCESS--------")
                print("JSON: \(String(describing: jsonObject))")

            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("--------------")
            print(error)
            jsonObject = false
        }
    }
    return jsonObject
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    nameField.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The Alamofire function is asynchronous, because it’s a network request. This means the function returns before the data from the  network request is returned, so it will always return nil because jsonObject is returned before it’s modified. What you need to do is pass in a callback function as a parameter, so that the callback function body gets called when the Alamofire function returns.

The callback signature could be something like this:
`callback: (T) -> ()`
Then inside the getReturnVal function you can call `callback(jsonObject)` right after the variable jsonObject is set (so twice). Then when you when you call getReturnVal you need to pass in a function that takes as a parameter that jsonObject.